# VBA INDEX MATCH MATCH LOOP

Tags: indexing, match

I am hoping that someone can show me how to use Index Match Match in a VBA loop.

I've been fighting with this for 3 days. Right now I can get the formual to work but not loop. Meaning that I will end up with a super long VBA code when finished.

This is what I'm using right now (ActiveSheet.Evaluate):

```
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1) = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=INDEX(ABsidecaps, MATCH(1,('Insert Lookup'!$H:$H=H3)*('Insert Lookup'!$I:$I=$A$5),0),4)")
```

This is finding information on another sheet by using 2 different cells on the current sheet.
Unfortunately, when I try to loop this to the next grouping of cells, the code ('Insert Lookup'!$H:$H=H3) will always remain as =H3 when I need to it to be =J3 instead.

Is there an easier way to do this is or am I going to have to type the whole code out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data in order to be able to help you?

Comment: cell "H1" is my ActiveCell, I need to fill "H5" with the text from the named range ABsidecaps (on the 'Insert Lookup' sheet), using "H3" which is a number, and "A5" which is a wording. The number is found within column '"H" on the 'Insert Lookup' sheet and the wording is found within coloum "I" on the 'Insert Lookup' sheet.
I just need "H3" to not be so specific a coloum so that when my ActiveCell changes to "J1" it wont be looking up "H3" still.

So that if "H3" is 1 and "J3" is 2, the formula looks up the wording for 2 and not the wording for 1